# How to make a Cross tabulation in R when each row doesn't represent a single case?

Tags: r, pivot-table, subset, frequency

I have a strange dataset that shows data similar to the following:

| Group | Subgroup | Sample Size | Response | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Education | High School | 1027 | Total | 100 |
| Education | High School |  | Yes | 32 |
| Education | High School |  | No | 68 |
| Education | Some College | 1052 | Total | 100 |
| Education | Some College |  | Yes | 35 |
| Education | Some College |  | No | 65 |

What I need to be able to do is create a table or crosstabulation showing the different subgroups of education by extracting the percent "yes" for the sample size.

I've been able to subset and extract using df[(df$Subgroup == "High School" & df$Response == "Yes") , ]$Percent but I haven't been able to extract multiple values and turn them into a table.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If the following is an accurate representation of your data:

[image: see image of data here]

Then you can use `filter` to select the rows in which response is "Yes" and `select` to only extract your variables of interest from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(Response == "Yes") %>% select(Subgroup, Percent)
```

[image: see image of result here]